# How to print hex string in linux shell with perl

Tags: perl

In linux shell, if I do `perl -e "print '\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f' x 10"`, the out put is:

> \x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f

But what I need is the ascii string of `\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f`, how to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape sequences like `\x6f` are only expanded in double-quoted strings. You have them in a single-quoted string. Reverse the use of quotes in your example (I've also added `-CS` to make the characters print properly):

```
$ perl -CS -e 'print "\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f" x 10'
oãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿoãÿÿÿ
```

**Update:** The [perlrun manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) explains about the various Perl command-line switches.

The `-C` switch controls various Unicode features. `-CS` is a quick way to tell Perl that the three standard filehandles (STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR) should be treated as providing or expecting a stream of UTF8-encoded data. This means that anything read from STDIN will be decoded from UTF8 to Perl characters and anything sent to STDOUT or STDERR will be encoded from Perl characters to UTF8. In this case, I only really needed `-CI` (which only applies that transformation to STDOUT) but I have got into the habit of handling all three filehandles together.

Comment: Double-quoted strings includes `qq`, so `perl -e "print qq(\x6f\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f) x 10"` would also work. This is useful on platforms like Windows where single quotes don't work on the command line.

Comment: You should explain about `-CS` rather than leaving it as an incantation!

Comment: @Borodin: Good idea. Done.